# Master Page Styles with Zurb Foundation and Sharepoint 2013

Tags: custom-masterpage

Recently I made a test Master Page that will use Zurb Foundation.  What I'm looking to gain by doing this is mostly just the easily manageable grid from Foundation as well as the dropdown menus. When I include the Foundation css files, many of the icons in the edit Page menus of Sharepoint do not load at all and their associated buttons are tiny. This is a bit of an issue, does anyone have any advice to offer on how to go about fixing this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I think you will have better chances at getting an answer on their Forum than here as it is a specific question about a 3rd party product.

Comment: Yeah I threw them a post as well just thought I'd check around.